# Kivy AsyncImage is not updated

Tags: kivy

I use a jpg image that is updated few times in a second as a source of AsyncImage in Kivy.
Although I remove the Image from the widgets tree, delete it ,and garbage collected it, I still get a static image that doesn't change.
I tried widget.canvas.ask_update(), and layout_instance.do_layout() with no results.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The image is cached. Try adding `nocache: True` to your kv (or `nocache=True` to your constructor call if you're creating it in Python).

Comment: I used a call to the contractor like this: self.newWid=Movie('http://192.168.1.102:8080/shot.jpg',nocache=True) it didn't work.

Comment: `Movie` is not a Kivy widget. The `nocache` property is on the `AsyncImage` widget. If you are creating your own custom widget, you need to pass the `nocache` argument to the `AsyncImage` instead.